# Spring MVC with Tomcat won't open Hello World html page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I'm trying to open a simple html page that writes Hello world, on localhost:8080/hello but it is inside a Spring MVC app. I use Spring Boot that comes with its own tomcat.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <display-name>Angular Rest Spring</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>angular</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>angular</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I tried putting the page inside:

```
app/src/main/resources
app/src/main/resources/templates
web
web/WEB-INF
```

It can't find it. It says:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Sep 07 15:52:20 EEST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Spring Boot? can you share your Configuration for spring context and how the project is structured? Why do you need a web.xml if you are running a spring boot app in its embedded Tomcat container?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring boot there is no need for writing a web.xml. Spring automatically maps all @Controller annotated classes and reads the @RequestMapping annotations from those.

Write an application class :

```
package com.sample.web;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.sample.web")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Write a controller class like like this:

```
package com.sample.web;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(Model model) {
        return "hello";
    }

}
```

And write a template html file in src/main/resources/templates :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
Hello
</body>
</html>
```

I use intellij in which I can run the application class which will then make the hello page available on http://localhost:8080/hello

Comment: Actually all of this is available in the spring boot docs here : 
https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Comment: I know this, this works but I want a page hello.html that isn't mapped to work. For example, the basic index.jsp doesn't work. When I go to localhost:8080/ it says page not found

Answer (score 0):

As far as i'm concerned, web pages in a spring boot application (using maven) go into:

**src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/**

This folder is basically the equivalent to **src/main/webapp** in a standard maven web app.

Comment: it stil lcan't find my static pages

Answer (score -1):

use [spring tool suite](https://spring.io/tools/sts/all) , create spring legacy project or spring starter project It will configure

Comment: But Im using spring boot, I want a solution for my configuration, not to change my entire project, thanks